# AWS SAM running local won't resolve FindInMap Intrinsic

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

I can't make a `template.yaml` with Mappings work when testing locally, although they will deploy and work as expected.

As an example, one can follow:

1. `sam init --runtime python3.8`
2. Insert Mappings such as the following in `template.yaml`

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  sam-app

  Sample SAM Template for sam-app

Parameters:
  Environment:
    Description: 'Required. Environment'
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - test
      - prod
    Default: test

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3
    MemorySize: !FindInMap [Environments, !Ref Environment, MemorySize]

Mappings:
  Environments:
    test:
      MemorySize: 512
    prod:
      MemorySize: 2048

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello_world/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get

Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn
```

3. `sam build --parameter-overrides ParamaterKey=Environment,ParameterValue=test --use-container`
4. `sam local start-api --debug`, and it will show unresolved references.

```
2021-03-06 00:30:42,394 | local start-api command is called
2021-03-06 00:30:42,399 | Collected default values for parameters: {'Environment': 'test'}
2021-03-06 00:30:42,417 | Unable to resolve property MemorySize: OrderedDict([('Fn::FindInMap', ['Environments', OrderedDict([('Ref', 'Environment')]), 'MemorySize'])]). Leaving as is.
2021-03-06 00:30:42,417 | 2 resources found in the stack 
2021-03-06 00:30:42,417 | Collected default values for parameters: {'Environment': 'test'}
2021-03-06 00:30:42,433 | Unable to resolve property MemorySize: OrderedDict([('Fn::FindInMap', ['Environments', OrderedDict([('Ref', 'Environment')]), 'MemorySize'])]). Leaving as is.
2021-03-06 00:30:42,434 | Collected default values for parameters: {'Environment': 'test'}
2021-03-06 00:30:42,449 | Unable to resolve property MemorySize: OrderedDict([('Fn::FindInMap', ['Environments', OrderedDict([('Ref', 'Environment')]), 'MemorySize'])]). Leaving as is.
2021-03-06 00:30:42,449 | Found Serverless function with name='HelloWorldFunction' and CodeUri='HelloWorldFunction'
2021-03-06 00:30:42,452 | Collected default values for parameters: {'Environment': 'test'}
2021-03-06 00:30:42,467 | Unable to resolve property MemorySize: OrderedDict([('Fn::FindInMap', ['Environments', OrderedDict([('Ref', 'Environment')]), 'MemorySize'])]). Leaving as is.
2021-03-06 00:30:42,467 | 2 resources found in the template
2021-03-06 00:30:42,468 | Found '1' API Events in Serverless function with name 'HelloWorldFunction'
2021-03-06 00:30:42,468 | Detected Inline Swagger definition
2021-03-06 00:30:42,468 | Lambda function integration not found in Swagger document at path='/hello' method='get'
2021-03-06 00:30:42,468 | Found '0' APIs in resource 'ServerlessRestApi'
2021-03-06 00:30:42,468 | Removed duplicates from '0' Explicit APIs and '1' Implicit APIs to produce '1' APIs
2021-03-06 00:30:42,468 | 1 APIs found in the template
2021-03-06 00:30:42,471 | Mounting HelloWorldFunction at http://127.0.0.1:3000/hello [GET]
2021-03-06 00:30:42,471 | You can now browse to the above endpoints to invoke your functions. You do not need to restart/reload SAM CLI while working on your functions, changes will be reflected instantly/automatically. You only need to restart SAM CLI if you update your AWS SAM template
2021-03-06 00:30:42,471 | Localhost server is starting up. Multi-threading = True
2021-03-06 00:30:42  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:3000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

5. Insist with `curl http://127.0.0.1/hello` and sam will show an error:

```
2021-03-06 00:33:25,099 | Found one Lambda function with name 'HelloWorldFunction'
2021-03-06 00:33:25,099 | Invoking app.lambda_handler (python3.8)
2021-03-06 00:33:25,099 | No environment variables found for function 'HelloWorldFunction'
2021-03-06 00:33:25,099 | Environment variables overrides data is standard format
2021-03-06 00:33:25,099 | Loading AWS credentials from session with profile 'None'
2021-03-06 00:33:25,113 | Resolving code path. Cwd=/home/ricardo/Sandbox/learning/aws/sam-app/.aws-sam/build, CodeUri=/home/ricardo/Sandbox/learning/aws/sam-app/.aws-sam/build/HelloWorldFunction
2021-03-06 00:33:25,113 | Resolved absolute path to code is /home/ricardo/Sandbox/learning/aws/sam-app/.aws-sam/build/HelloWorldFunction
2021-03-06 00:33:25,113 | Code /home/ricardo/Sandbox/learning/aws/sam-app/.aws-sam/build/HelloWorldFunction is not a zip/jar file
2021-03-06 00:33:25,127 | Skip pulling image and use local one: amazon/aws-sam-cli-emulation-image-python3.8:rapid-1.19.1.

2021-03-06 00:33:25,127 | Mounting /home/ricardo/Sandbox/learning/aws/sam-app/.aws-sam/build/HelloWorldFunction as /var/task:ro,delegated inside runtime container
2021-03-06 00:33:25,127 | Cleaning all decompressed code dirs
2021-03-06 00:33:25,128 | Exception on /hello [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ricardo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/utils/utils.py", line 415, in parse_bytes
    digits = int(digits_part)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "OrderedDict([('Fn::FindInMap', ['Environments', OrderedDict([('Ref', 'Environment')]), 'MemorySize'])])"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ricardo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ricardo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/ricardo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/ricardo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/ricardo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ricardo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/ricardo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/local/apigw/local_apigw_service.py", line 297, in _request_handler
    self.lambda_runner.invoke(route.function_name, event, stdout=stdout_stream_writer, stderr=self.stderr)
  File "/home/ricardo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/commands/local/lib/local_lambda.py", line 111, in invoke
    self.local_runtime.invoke(config, event, debug_context=self.debug_context, stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr)
  File "/home/ricardo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/telemetry/metric.py", line 216, in wrapped_func
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ricardo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/local/lambdafn/runtime.py", line 148, in invoke
    container = self.create(function_config, debug_context)
  File "/home/ricardo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/local/lambdafn/runtime.py", line 82, in create
    self._container_manager.create(container)
  File "/home/ricardo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/local/docker/manager.py", line 95, in create
    container.create()
  File "/home/ricardo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/local/docker/container.py", line 167, in create
    real_container = self.docker_client.containers.create(self._image, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ricardo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/models/containers.py", line 860, in create
    create_kwargs = _create_container_args(kwargs)
  File "/home/ricardo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/models/containers.py", line 1077, in _create_container_args
    create_kwargs['host_config'] = HostConfig(**host_config_kwargs)
  File "/home/ricardo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/types/containers.py", line 182, in __init__
    self['Memory'] = parse_bytes(mem_limit)
  File "/home/ricardo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/utils/utils.py", line 417, in parse_bytes
    raise errors.DockerException(
docker.errors.DockerException: Failed converting the string value for memory (OrderedDict([('Fn::FindInMap', ['Environments', OrderedDict([('Ref', 'Environment')]), 'MemorySize'])])) to an integer.
```

- `sam --version` gives `SAM CLI, version 1.19.1`.

Isn't FindInMap intrinsic still not implemented? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 2022: I'm having the same problem. By any chance do you have any news about this?

I'm asking Amazon Web Services (AWS) support, maybe they know what is happening.

Comment: Hi @jgomo3, I abandoned this approach entirely at the time, so I don't know how it followed up, but there was an issue for that on SAM's github. I remember they picking it to work at some point but couldn't wait for the result, I stopped following.